# Pressing `Shift+Tab` after selecting multiple lines in VSCode should reindent them, but it doesn't

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding

```
Version: 1.82.0
Commit: 8b617bd08fd9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314
Date: 2023-09-06T22:07:18.759Z
Electron: 25.8.0
ElectronBuildId: 23503258
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.2.0-32-generic
```

Reindenting lines using `Shift+Tab` doesn't work despite the fact that this keybinding is in the system settings. (`Tab Moves Focus` was always off)
[image: System keyboard shortcuts]
I tried to add this combination to other settings, but my attempts were in vain. [image: User keyboard shortcut]
After I restarted the window and ran `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting`, I received this error:

```
2023-09-10 23:05:10.764 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-09-10 23:05:10.811 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2023-09-10 23:05:10.812 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 16, key: Shift
2023-09-10 23:05:10.812 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 4 ('Shift')
2023-09-10 23:05:10.812 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2023-09-10 23:05:10.898 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-09-10 23:05:10.900 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving shift+[Tab]
2023-09-10 23:05:10.906 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 6 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.reindentselectedlines, when: no when condition, source: user.
2023-09-10 23:05:10.908 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [shift], code: Tab, keyCode: 9, key: Tab
2023-09-10 23:05:10.910 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [shift], code: Tab, keyCode: 2 ('Tab')
2023-09-10 23:05:10.912 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving shift+[Tab]
2023-09-10 23:05:10.914 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 6 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.reindentselectedlines, when: no when condition, source: user.
2023-09-10 23:05:10.915 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command editor.action.reindentselectedlines.
2023-09-10 23:05:11.208 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier shift due to it being pressed together with other keys.
```

After hitting `Shift+Tab` a few times I got a few of these errors and then I started getting a different type of error:

```
2023-09-10 23:07:37.225 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-09-10 23:07:37.228 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2023-09-10 23:07:37.230 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 16, key: Shift
2023-09-10 23:07:37.231 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 4 ('Shift')
2023-09-10 23:07:37.232 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2023-09-10 23:07:37.331 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-09-10 23:07:37.332 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving shift+[Tab]
2023-09-10 23:07:37.333 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 6 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.reindentselectedlines, when: no when condition, source: user.
2023-09-10 23:07:37.333 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [shift], code: Tab, keyCode: 9, key: Tab
2023-09-10 23:07:37.334 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [shift], code: Tab, keyCode: 2 ('Tab')
2023-09-10 23:07:37.335 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving shift+[Tab]
2023-09-10 23:07:37.338 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 6 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.reindentselectedlines, when: no when condition, source: user.
2023-09-10 23:07:37.339 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command editor.action.reindentselectedlines.
2023-09-10 23:07:37.507 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Storing single modifier for possible chord shift.
2023-09-10 23:07:37.525 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Clearing single modifier due to other key up.
```

I was here([Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/160515)). But it is not my case.
Unfortunately, I did not find the answer to my question on the Internet.
The code I tried to reindent was in Python. I only have basic extensions.

Comment: show a minimal example of code that can be used to reproduce this behaviour. sometimes I've observed that with mixed tabs and space, if you want tabs, spaces will not be converted to tabs.